# Is System Access Token a secure way to execute azure pipelines?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, oauth, azure-pipelines, access-token

I want to run pipelines from a powershell script, and I want to do that in a secured way.

Today my powershell code runs the pipelines with System access token ( I'm talking about [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) ) by calling the REST API for Azure DevOps; I see that the URL of the API is the same as the public one.

What would happen if someone listening to the traffic discovers the System Access Token value in the request? I would like to find a way to avoid public traffic, we are avoiding PAT (Personal Access Token).

What are the risks of calling pipelines from powershell in the same azure devops server with System Access Token and a public URI of the API?

Comment: This is what TLS is for :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what do you mean? :)

Comment: TLS - Transport Layer Security - the record protocol that puts the **s** in http**s** :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ah ok , I get it, so the calls made in the https URL should be secured without risks of listening traffic? I'm not looking for a 100% of security :)

Comment: TLS doesn't prevent tapping/listening on whatever transport it's carried over - but it does encrypt the application traffic (including any tokens you send in HTTP headers) so it's near-impossible for an eavesdropper to make out what the  contents of the traffic is - instead of "Here is Elias' Access Token: ABC123", then eavesdropper would see random garbage.

Answer (score 1):

The **`System.AccessToken`** (**`job access token`**) is a security token that is dynamically generated by Azure Pipelines for each job at run time.

This means that the token is generated when the job is started up and revoked when the job is completed. And each time when you run the pipeline job, it will generated a new token for use.

The valid period of a **`System.AccessToken`** is not long-term. And our Azure DevOps also have taken the effective measures to prevent the token from being leaked when used in the pipeline.

So, you can use the **`System.AccessToken`** in your pipeline with confidence.

For more details, you can see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).